# CentOS - how to tell what conf file CSF (firewall) is using? csf.conf then restart not updating

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, csf

in /etc/csf/csf.conf the following is setup

```
LF_CPANEL = "5"
LF_CPANEL_PERM = "3600"
```

restarting csf by doing the following

```
csf -r
```

does not seem to have an impact on the above attributes.
According to this log;

```
(cpanel) Failed cPanel login from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 2 in the last 300 secs - *Blocked in csf* [LF_CPANEL]
```

I restarted IPtables, CSF and it still does not take the changes.
There is only one instance of LF_CPANEL in /etc/csf/csf.conf

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question,
the lfd (login failure daemon) needed to be restarted also.